# Set up TAP networking for QEMU on macOS host

Tags: macos, qemu

I have been trying to set up internet access for an Ubuntu Server (*yes*, it has to be an Ubuntu Server, even though I would prefer something lightweight like Alpine) on a macOS host. As far as I understand, I need to use Tap/Tun networking.

### What I have done so far:

- Installed [TunTap OSX](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net), so I have a `/dev/tap0` device.
- Set up a `bridge1` network device using ifconfig
- Set the IP of the `bridge1` device to `192.168.100.1/24`.
- Assigned IP `192.168.100.0` to tap0.
- Set up a DHCP server and packet forwarding as per [this site](https://rambling-ideas.salessandri.name/setup-nat-network-for-qemu-in-mac-osx/)
- Made scripts to `addm` and `deletem` `tap0` from `bridge1` at startup and shutdown of the VM. (I have verified these are working).

### Apparent problems

At this point, WireShark shows no traffic through `tap0`, but all my loopback traffic seems to pass through `bridge1`.

The Ubuntu Server guest still does not have any internet access. I cannot send any data from the host to the guest or vice versa (I've tried `ssh` and a netcat listener/client pair).

Running `ip link show` in the guest shows only 2 devices: `lo0` and `ens3`. When the Ubuntu Server boots, the latter is always DOWN until I run `ip link set ens3 up` (which doesn't fix anything).

When I used to run this VM on VirtualBox (which seems to be broken on macOS now), networking worked perfectly using a virtual NAT. I converted the `.vdi` image to `.qcow2`, so everything in the quest OS is identical to how it was before.

Have I done anything wrong here? If so, what can I fix? And if not, what should my next steps be? I appreciate your consideration.

### Data Dumps

`bridge1` when the VM is running:

```
$ ifconfig bridge1

bridge1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether fa:ff:c2:96:c0:01 
    inet 192.168.100.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.100.255
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: tap0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 15 priority 0 path cost 0
    Address cache:
        52:54:0:12:34:56 Vlan1 tap0 992 flags=0<>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

`bridge1` when the VM is *not* running:

```
$ ifconfig bridge1

bridge1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether fa:ff:c2:96:c0:01 
    inet 192.168.100.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.100.255
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    Address cache:
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

`tap0` when the VM is *not* running:

```
$ ifconfig tap0

ifconfig: interface tap0 does not exist
```

`tap0` when the VM is running:

```
$ ifconfig tap0

tap0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 7e:9b:23:d0:c2:97 
    media: autoselect
    status: active
    open (pid 2415)
```

My QEMU command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 1024m \
-smp 1 \
-boot d \
-hda Server.qcow2 \
-net nic,model=virtio \
-net tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=qemu-ifup.sh,downscript=qemu-ifdown.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want NAT-networking configured for your VMs automatically, you can just 1) share your Internet connection to the bridge interface in the System Preferences, and 2) add the tapN-interfaces of your VMs to the bridge. Easy!

See more details here - https://gist.github.com/andriytk/bd3def8c30cbd474490280436c779027.

Comment: In the last 3 months, I've changed all sorts of configurations, and moved the VM to a Raspberry Pi due to the difficulties I was having on macOS. I'll remember this in case I ever need to set up another VM. I had no idea I could share internet that way.